# jQuery action after "switch" event

Tags: jquery, load, switch-statement

I created a map where a user can walk from one building to another. Next to the map there's a small minimap. The "big" map just refreshes by using the load() command. I have got the following code:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {

        switch (event.keyCode) {

            // A
            case 65: $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=w"); break;

            // W
            case 87: $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=n"); break;

            // D
            case 68: $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=e"); break;

            // S
            case 83: $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=s"); break;

        }

    });
```

Now, right after pressing one of the keys, I want the following to be executed:

```
$("#minimap").load("../modules/Minimap.php");
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Just put that code below the switch. Is that what you want?

Comment: Do you want to execute this command after the key was pressed or the corresponding map has been loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices, but first, let's refactor slightly (I'll refactor more in a moment, but let's start with this):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var direction;

    switch (event.keyCode) {

        // A
        case 65: direction = 'w'; break;

        // W
        case 87: direction = 'n'; break;

        // D
        case 68: direction = 'e'; break;

        // S
        case 83: direction = 's'; break;
    }

    if (direction) {
        $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=" + direction);
    }
});
```

Now the first load is centralized and we're not repeating ourselves.

Okay, you have two choices:

1. Put it after the `switch` statement if you want both `load`s to happen at the same time. E.g., picking up at the end:

   ```
   if (direction) {
       $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=" + direction);
       $("#minimap").load("../modules/Minimap.php");
   }
   ```

   I've assumed there that we only want to do it if a key matched. If I'm wrong, move it out of the `if`.
2. Use the `success` callback on the first `load` if you want the second load to wait until the first one is complete.

   ```
   if (direction) {
       $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=" + direction, function() {
           // This gets called when the load completes
           $("#minimap").load("../modules/Minimap.php");
       });
   }
   ```

More in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

---

Here's the more thoroughly refactored version: Have this:

```
var directionKeyMap = {
    '65': 'w',  // A
    '87': 'n',  // W
    '68': 'e',  // D
    '83': 's'   // S
};
```

And then either this (option 1 above):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var direction;

    direction = directionKeyMap[event.keyCode];
    if (direction) {
        $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=" + direction);
        $("#minimap").load("../modules/Minimap.php");
    }
});
```

Or this (option 2 above):

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var direction;

    direction = directionKeyMap[event.keyCode];
    if (direction) {
        $("#world").load("../modules/Map.php?go&move=" + direction, function() {
            $("#minimap").load("../modules/Minimap.php");
        });
    }
});
```

Those use an object to map keycodes to directions, taking advantage of the fact you can look up object properties using bracketed notation.

(Don't worry that `keyCode` is a number but the keys in our map are strings; whenever you use bracketed notation, whatever you give is converted to a string by the JavaScript interpreter. In fact, that's the case even when you index into an array, since JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). But again, we're using a plain object, not an array.)

Comment: Now that your answer is a proper super set of mine, I can delete it :P :D (gave you +1 anyway ;)). Happy code optimization! :)

Comment: @Felix: LOL! Hadn't seen yours before you deleted it or I'd've upvoted it. I'm laughing at the similarity. Great minds and all that...

Comment: Thanks there! Very well explained.